# How to configure tsconfig.json for typings not in @types?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I'm using a tsconfig.json file to specify which typings I want to use in my app.

```
{
   "compilerOptions": {
       "types" : ["node", "lodash", "express"]
   }
}
```

This imports typings from `./node_modules/@types/node`, `./node_modules/@types/lodash` and `./node_modules/@types/expres`.

My question is how can I configure typings for self-contained modules?

My example is the zone.js package which has both the library code and type definitions.

- ./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js
- ./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.min.js
- **./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.d.ts**

What do I put in my tsconfig.json file to include `zone.js.d.ts`?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You just have to add `zone.js` to the `types` in your `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
   "compilerOptions": {
       "types" : ["node", "lodash", "express", "zone.js"]
   }
}
```

Note that you do not have to include all types like this. Type definitions from the `@types/*` packages are automatically included.

So you could remove the types declaration in your `tsconfig.json` and all the `@types/*` packages would be automatically referenced.

In order to get `zone.js` to work you can either include it in a single file like this:

```
/// <reference types="zone.js" />
```

Or if you want it available in your whole project you can add a `index.d.ts` at the root of your project and put int the reference there.

Comment: Adding it to the `types` array works. Strange that it didn't work for me the first time I tried it. I guess my editor was lagging behind.

Comment: Note that you should add the name of the installed package in the `types`. For example, if you run: `npm install chrome-types`, then you would put `chrome-types` in there (without the .js).

Answer (score 15):

You can place the file anywhere, but you need to tell the compiler about it, either by adding it in `tsconfig.json` or as a `///<reference>`. For `tsconfig` add the `include` field:

```
{
    "compileOnSave": false,
    "compilerOptions": {
        ..
    },
    "include": [
        "zone.d.ts",
    ]
}
```