# How do I include the type definition of a node module package?

Tags: typescript, vuejs3

I am trying to include the Typescript type definition from the vue-router 4 package, so I can use one of their types to build up an array of routes, just to see if I can get nicer errors instead of the monstrosity that I currently generate when creating a pre-filled array. Currently I get the following error though when trying to define an array with the `RouteRecordRaw` type:

```
TS2304: Cannot find name 'RouteRecordRaw'.
```

This is defined in `node_modules/vue-router/dist/vue-router.d.ts`. My tsconfig.json contains the `compilerOptions` key with the `types` key in it. From what I understand it will try to find all folders defined under `types` under whatever is defined in `typeRoots`. If `typeRoots` isn't defined, it will use the default `[ 'node_modules/@types' ]`. I tried playing around with this by adding `node_modules`, `node_modules/vue-router` and `node_modules/vue-router/dist` and adding `vue-router` and `dist` to `types`, but not much seemed to be happening.

I tried adding a comment `/// <reference types="vue-router" />` as suggested in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48704150/how-to-configure-tsconfig-json-for-typings-not-in-types), which is picked up by typescript (if I misspell it, it will error out), but no help there either.

I also seem unable to include the type definitions any other way (unless I copy/paste it to my own type file I guess, but I would like to avoid that). The type is exported in the earlier mentioned file as `export declare type RouteRecordRaw = RouteRecordSingleView | RouteRecordMultipleViews | RouteRecordRedirect;`. Is there another way to include this type definition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, it is not required to do any of the things I did. I already had a `import * as VueRouter from 'vue-router';` at the top of the file. As it turns out, you can import types in the same way as you import anything else. The correct syntax turned out to be:

```
export const routes: VueRouter.RouteRecordRaw[] = [];
```